# Please help me understand why the FPS are so low in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, android-webview, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to optimise a webapp we created for better performance on Android devices and I'm using the latest official Chrome build on my first generation Nexus 7 attached to an android debug bridge.

I use the chrome devtools timeline to try to figure out what is causing the crappy scrolling performance I get int he webapp.

While looking at the timeline I noticed that when leaving the webapp just sitting there in each frame I have the following Records:

[image]

As far as I understand this, there's too much to do in each frame with plenty of time left. Or at least there should be. If painting takes 7.654ms and 1.577ms of non-instrumented stuff going on, what takes the CPU 21.818ms AND what causes the idle time of approx. 80ms between frames?

[image]

The timeline is not filtered in any way, so I'm pretty unsure how to find out what's going on.

The webapp I'm trying to optimise is located at http://www.vol.at/?forcemobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 9 FPS you're seeing when the page isn't scrolling seems to be coming from a timer that's causing a DOM update. This is why there is a lot of time between "frames". That FPS name is somewhat confusing, the counter you want is the one you get when you click on the DevTools "settings" cog in the lower right and enable "Show FPS meter".

You really want to be recording when you're scrolling though - the page will not render @60fps when you're not doing anything - try it - just load about:blank (or some very simple page) and try recording the Timeline - you should see none (or very few) events.

Scrolling performance is a very complex topic and I'd like to direct you to [jankfree.org](http://jankfree.org/). That page contains tons of high quality talks and tutorials. You may want to look at [the scrolling performance tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/) and [this Google IO talk](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325933151) to get you started.

From a very brief look at your page it seems like:

- there is a timer firing at a very rapid rate on the page, you should investigate that  since just sitting on the page, doing nothing is draining user's batteries.
- whenever you finish scrolling a pretty expensive script is triggered from onScroll. That also seems to trigger a raster of the entire page. Try removing the onscroll handler and seeing if the page is less janky, if so you should try and optimize that.
- when you click on an article the ads are positioned using JavaScript, not CSS positioning, these will always lag as you scroll. You should consider using `position: fixed`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! In the meantime I figured out what was the main cause for the jaggieness when scrolling and I can achieve ~30fps.